# What to do with an interesting idea about sensor design?

Tags: sensor

I think I've had a cool idea to replace the Bayer pattern in sensors with something better, but I'm not even sure if it's definitively an improvement.

It's not something too complicated, just a different arrangement of the photo diodes with an array not made of equal squares (I drew inspiration from Fuji's Super CCD and X-Trans sensors, plus sensors with panchromatic diodes); so it might have already occurred to somebody else and was discarded because it was technically unfeasible or impractical.

So my possible options would be:

- Give up and forget about it (I'm not that smart after all).
- Go for it:

  1. Research more the state of the art, read patents, etc. to see if it has been tried already.
  2. Make simple computer model and simulate to see if there are any improvements, at least under optimal conditions.
  3. Fill a patent and try to sell it.
- Give it away for free: I think It's better that somebody else makes profit of a good idea than letting it go to waste. Maybe send an e-mail to the R&D department of a camera manufacturer telling them the idea and asking them if it was worth at least to consider.

Any other ideas?

Comment: I think to get any credibility you must start with point 2. It's not that difficult to do a basic simulation and it costs nothing but your time. (A proper study would take quite a bit more effort than a basic simulation though ...) A patent application is expensive.  You should also familiarize yourself with various Bayer demosaicing algorithms before you do 2., ask a friend in academia to help you download the papers.

Comment: thanks for the idea; I will try some demosaicing tests before anything :)

Comment: As I understand your idea, it is already in production. It was documented in Photonics, earlier this year. The sensor response was better with varying pixel size. It was also observed that different pixel shapes were more optimal than square pixels in some ways. Don't take my word for it, though, research your concept.

Comment: IANAL / I am not a Patent Attorney. I am an engineer - the following is opinion. : My understandings are: If you are in the US then if you document your idea as ful;ly as possible and sign and date it and ideally prove in some manner that it existed on that date then yuou have one year to patent it. ASfyter that if unpatented it is not able to be and is public domain if you have disclosed it. In the US, public disclosure is the same as above and gives you one year to patent it. | In my country (NZ) disclosure makes the idea instant PD if unpatented. But a provisional 1 year patent that ...

Comment: ... gives priority date costs $50. You can search etc and pay **BIG** dollars but no need usually. USPTO used to have a "send us a sealed envelope and we will; date stamp it and keep it for one year" scheme. May no longer exist.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "better", most sensors do a few things very well, and the remaining improvements to general sensor technology has to do with doing more things well at the same time. A lot of flaws in current sensors are shared through out all sensors - i.e. the issues don't arise from a Bayer CFA (Color Filter Array), confusingly many people conflate a general sensor issue with a CFA issue.  Your opinion of how this is better would be the minimum needed for feedback. Esp. because of your need for secrecy. We'll also be able to see if you have a clue about sensors too.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, The US patent system changed dramatically in the past year. We no longer have "first-to-invent", instead we have a backdoor kind of first-to-file system. I don't know if there is still a one year window for filing after public disclosure or not.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say a mixture of give up about it, discuss it with others (electronics.stackexchange.com might be good) and simulate it.

1. **Give up about it**. Designing sensors is a very complicated process (I did an internship in a research lab about this once). You can do it at home because the software needed is available. The software is very expensive ([list of software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_design_automation#Companies)) but you could buy it. Next, you need experience and time to do the design. You can then have your chip fabricated by specialised companies. If I remember correctly, the cost for the imaging chips (low resolution) were around $5k but this was a few years ago and I might be mistaken.
2. **Discuss it with others / Research**. Note, do not send it unsolicited to R&D departments of manufacturers or universities. But, ask people about your idea. They might be able to tell you whether it has been done before, or point out obvious oversights.  Also, you should do some basic research. Read about existing technologies and so on.
3. **Simulate**. I would not recommend a computer simulation but rather a mathematical simulation. Show on pen and paper that your idea shows the improvement over the Bayer pattern. This is probably easier than you think, and it will be *proof* and with it you can go to others. They can then quickly determine whether you are right. That is not possible with a computer simulation. You can of course publish your code and have others check it, but they won't do that. Show this concept on papers and others will believe you.

Also, you would like to clearly define what your **improvement** is! Is it going to give better resolution, colour representation, manufacturing costs, etc.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I've just seen a patent that is very similar to the idea I had (using triangular sensels), so I'm going to disclose what I thought just for reference.

http://www.faqs.org/patents/app/20130056617

And here are described similar (with full hexagonal pixels) designs:
http://www.quadibloc.com/other/cfaint.htm

It's fairly recent though, so I can have at least the satisfaction of knowing that I wasn't off by too much :)

Here's a diagram of the CFA as I imagined it:

[image: triangular tessellation RGBW Colour Filter Array]

It was an RGBW with the nicety that the distribution of colours is quite symmetrical. Each hexagon has the three primary colours plus 50% of panchromatic sensitivity, which should be quite nice to reduce noise.

I am still thinking how to get a nice rectangular pattern of pixels after demosaicing (without loosing too much resolution)... The cool thing is that the hexagons overlap nicely, but the odd rows are offset by half the width of a triangle and that would require some ugly interpolation.